# Fast Paced Shooter (30 seconds)

Tags: python, python-3.x

A fast paced shooter which counts and displays your kills. If you are to copy and paste this code also copy the images and save them as png files with names in the code

[image: crosshair.png] [image: Donald.png][image: hitler.png]

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import timeit


pygame.init()

display_width = 1600
display_height = 850
speed = [1, -1]

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
grey = (177,177,177)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Kill hitler before he gets trump')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

crosshairImg = pygame.image.load('crosshair.PNG')
hitlerImg = pygame.image.load('hitler.png')
donaldImg = pygame.image.load('donald.png')

def crosshair(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(crosshairImg, (x,y))

def enemy(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(hitlerImg, (x,y))

def friendly(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(donaldImg, (x,y))
def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',45)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, red)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def status(total, enemy_kills):
    if total == 0:
        status = 0
    else:
        status = round((enemy_kills/total)*100, 2)

    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
    text = font.render('Status:'+str(status)+'%', True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,30))

def score(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render('Confirmed Enemy Kills:'+str(count), True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,0))

def timer(count):
    count = round(count, 1)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render('time left:'+str(count), True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,45))

def friend_kill(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None,25)
    text = font.render('Confirmed Friendly Kills:'+str(count), True, blue)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(0,15))

def gameloop():
    thing_startx = (display_width/2)
    thing_starty = (display_height/2)
    thing_xspeed = 0
    thing_yspeed = 0

    enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-20))
    enemy_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-20))
    enemy_xspeed = 0
    enemy_yspeed = 0

    friend_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-40))
    friend_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-40))
    friend_width = 40
    friend_height = 40
    friend_xspeed = 0
    friend_yspeed = 0

    ammo = 5

    kills = 0

    total_kills = 0

    friendly_kills = 0

    gameExit = False

    start = time.time()

    elapsed = 0

    while not gameExit and elapsed < 30:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                thing_startx = event.pos[0]-37
                thing_starty = event.pos[1]-37

        thing_startx += thing_xspeed
        thing_starty += thing_yspeed

        gameDisplay.fill (grey)
        score(kills)
        status(total_kills, kills)
        friend_kill(friendly_kills)
        timer((30-elapsed))

        enemy(enemy_startx, enemy_starty)
        friendly(friend_startx, friend_starty)
        crosshair(thing_startx, thing_starty)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (event.pos[0] > enemy_startx and event.pos[0] < enemy_startx+45) and event.pos[1] > enemy_starty and event.pos[1] < enemy_starty+60:
                enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-45))
                enemy_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-60))
                friend_startx = random.randrange(0,(display_width-40))
                friend_starty = random.randrange(0,(display_height-40))
                kills += 1
                total_kills += 1

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if (event.pos[0] > friend_startx and event.pos[0] < friend_startx+60) and event.pos[1] > friend_starty and event.pos[1] < friend_starty+80:
                friend_startx = random.randrange(0,(display_width-40))
                friend_starty = random.randrange(0,(display_height-40))
                enemy_startx = random.randrange(0, (display_width-45))
                enemy_starty = random.randrange(0, (display_height-60))
                friendly_kills += 1
                total_kills += 1
                message_display('you killed a friendly')
                time.sleep(1)

        if (kills>=5 and kills<10) or (kills>=15 and kills<20):
            if enemy_startx+45<display_width and enemy_xspeed not in (1, -1):
                enemy_xspeed += 1
            if friend_startx+60<display_width and friend_xspeed not in (1,-1):
                friend_xspeed += 1

            if enemy_startx>0 and enemy_xspeed not in (-1, 0):
                enemy_xspeed = 1
            if friend_startx>0 and friend_xspeed not in (-1, 0):
                friend_xspeed = 1

        elif kills>=10 and kills<20:
            if enemy_starty+60<display_height and enemy_yspeed not in (1, -1):
                enemy_yspeed += 1
            if friend_starty+80<display_width and friend_yspeed not in (1,-1):
                friend_yspeed += 1

            if enemy_starty>0 and enemy_yspeed not in (-1, 0):
                enemy_yspeed = 1
            if friend_starty>0 and friend_yspeed not in (-1, 0):
                friend_yspeed = 1

        elif kills>=20:
            if enemy_startx+45<display_height and enemy_xspeed not in (2, -2):
                enemy_xspeed = 2
            if friend_startx+60<display_height and friend_xspeed not in (2, -2):
                friend_xspeed = 2

            if enemy_starty>0 and enemy_yspeed not in (2, -2):
                enemy_yspeed = -2
            if friend_starty>0 and friend_yspeed not in (2, -2):
                friend_yspeed = -2

        else:
            enemy_xspeed = 0
            enemy_yspeed = 0
            friend_xspeed = 0
            friend_yspeed = 0

        if enemy_startx+45>display_width or enemy_startx<0:
            enemy_xspeed *= -1
        if enemy_starty+60>display_height or enemy_starty<0:
            enemy_yspeed *= -1

        if friend_startx+40>display_width or friend_startx<0:
            friend_xspeed *= -1
        if friend_starty+40>display_height or friend_starty<0:
            friend_yspeed *= -1            

        enemy_starty += enemy_yspeed        
        enemy_startx += enemy_xspeed
        friend_startx += friend_xspeed
        friend_starty += friend_yspeed

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)
        elapsed = time.time() - start
        msg = 'you got',kills,'enemy kills amd',friendly_kills,'enemy kills'
    message_display('you got '+str(kills)+' enemy kills and '+str(friendly_kills)+' friendly kills')
    time.sleep(2)
    gameloop()

gameloop()
```

Comment: There is an "enter code here" in the middle of the code that let me wondering if you correctly pasted your code in the question. Can you double check that it is indeed correct? You should also try to provide a better description of your code (maybe shrink down the title to "Fast paced shooter game") and incorporate more details about what it is you have done.

Comment: This question is incomplete and the code is carelessly posted. As it currently stands, it won't run for the reason mentioned by @Mathias. This question is also lacking context. Please provide more information about what the code does and how.

Comment: I'm sorry about the fault in the pasting. I carelessly didn't check

Comment: @Mast. I hope my edits have changed everything necessary

Answer (score 2):

## style

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) asks that you use underscore in identifiers, e.g. `donald_img`.

Introducing some vertical space between `friendly()` and `message_display()` would be helpful. PEP8 asks for 2 blank lines.

In some lengthy conditionals, e.g. `if (event.pos[0] > enemy_startx ...`, you have an opportunity to take advantage of the open paren, so you can break the conditional into multiple lines, each a maximum of 80 characters.

## def main()

Even for a game, it is customary to ensure that `foo.py` can be safely imported (`import foo`) without unfortunate side effects and without polluting the global namespace. This is usually accomplished by burying top-level statements in main(), invoked under `if __name__ == '__main__':`. The statements from pygame.init() through loading donald.png would benefit from being moved into `main()`. If those identifiers really do need to be in the global namespace, then names like DONALD_IMG would be more appropriate.

## hoisting constants

In `status()`, maybe the font assignment should be a one-time global assignment. Oh, wait, I see that in several methods. I'm just saying that maybe evaluating `SysFont()` is more expensive than you'd like, and you would prefer to do it just once.

## representing two dimensions

For friend and for enemy, there are numerous parallel X & Y quantities. This suggests modeling the quantities as (x, y), or (x_speed, y_speed), tuples.